# C# Append Text with Specific text format

Tags: c#, file, append

So guyz , I use a classic StringBuilder to create some text so I can "Append" it to a text file. 
Everything works fine but I need the text file to have a specific look so i need a price(for example  32) to be shown as ( 00032.0000 ) . 
To make the "32" show up in the TxT file I use this code.

```
calcprice = Convert.ToInt32(printquant) * Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[counter4].Cells[category].Value);
                    printprice = calcprice.ToString();
                    csvcontent.AppendLine(printprice);
```

Comment: Investigate string.Format.

Comment: maybe AppendFormat  ?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better in your case. Forgot about that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the built in ToString formatter

```
int printPrice = 32;
printPrice.ToString("00000.0000") //-> 00032.0000
```

Comment: one more thing though ....  ( No Overload for Method 'ToString' takes 1 arguement) I get this error when I try to apply this formula on another string.

Comment: @SymeonLaftsopoulos cant do this on a string. Have to do it on a number type

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the overload of `.ToString()` that accepts that format as a parameter like this:

```
printprice = calcprice.ToString("00000.0000");
```